# IOException: unexpected end of stream on okhttp3 (Retrofit2)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava

Мне приходит с сервера JSON такого формата:

```
{"user":[{"username":"admin",   
"name":"Administrator",   
"email":"admin@example.com",   
"properties":  
{"property":
{"@key":"console.order"  
,"@value":"session-summary=0"}}},  
{"username":"alice",  
"name":"Alice",   
"email":"alice@abc.com"  
,"properties":null}]}
```

Получаю ошибку в методе getUsers(), а именно: `java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.Address`

и `Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=.` Не могу понять чем эта ошибка может быть вызвана? и как ее исправить?

Если в классе User, использую String properties, вместо Properties properties, то получаю ошибку: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`

Метод `getUsers()`:

```
     private void getUsers() {
            String credentials = "admin" + ":" + "admin";
            final String basic =
                    "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            String contentType = "application/json";
            String accept = "application/json";
            Subscription subscription = App.service.users(basic, contentType, accept)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(users -> {
                        contacts.addAll(users);
  Log.e("Users", users.toString());
                        contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }, throwable -> {

                    });

            addSubscription(subscription);
        }
```

Сам API:

```
public interface MessengerApi {
    @GET("users")
    Observable<List<User>> users(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                 @Header("Content-type") String   contentType,
                                 @Header("Accept") String accept);
}
```

Класс User:

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("username")
    String username;
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    String email;
    @SerializedName("properties")
    private Properties properties;

    public User(String username, String name, String email, Properties properties) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

Класс Properties:

```
public class Properties {

    @SerializedName("property")
    private Property property;

    public Property getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
}
```

Класс Property:

```
public class Property {

    @SerializedName("@key")
    private String key;

    @SerializedName("@value")
    private String value;

    public Property(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Property(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавила класс Users:

```
public class Users {

    @SerializedName("user")
    List<User> user;
//getters and setters
}
```

Изменила код в интерфейсе API:

```
@GET("users")
    Observable<Users> users(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                            @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
                            @Header("Accept") String accept);
```

После этого заработало.